# RStudio uses wrong project path for a git repository

Tags: git, rstudio

I have a RStudio (ver 1.1.414) project in a server whose path is of the form

```
//server/path/project
```

I would like to create a git path to this path and use it via RStudio.

However, if a create a git repository via `Tools->Project Options->Git/SVN->Version control system`: `git`, the repository does not point to the above server path, but to Windows 7 path `C:\Windows` (!). I even accidentally created git repository to `C:\Windows`, but removed it.

Interestingly enough, if I try to do from RStudio `Git -> (cogwheel icon) Settings -> Shell..`, it goes to correct project path. But even if I did `git init` from the shell, RStudio did not change its git path from `C:\Windows\` to the correct project path.

Seems like the path is correct for the commands behind the git (cogwheel) settings menu:

[image]

because invoking `Ignore` command created file `.gitignore` into the correct project path.

But behind the Git menu, all the paths point to the wrong path:

[image]

I tried to look for duplicate request, but unlike in similar questions, I am *not* suggesting to use other than project folder for git repository.

**EDIT:** Updated to from RStudio version 1.0.153 to version 1.1.414, but the problem remained: `Tools->Project Options->Git/SVN->Version control system: git` created repository to `C:\Windows`.

Comment: Various people seem to report problems with RStudio+Git+UNC paths (the //foo/bar paths). Try asking at http://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. Same question is now asked also in [Rstudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/git-in-rstudio-does-not-recognize-path-in-unc-format/4414).

Comment: As a workaround it was suggested to map UNC path to a local drive. But it would be nice that UNC paths would work directly.